# Emberjs: Internet Explorer not showing changes to model unless page is refreshed

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem with Internet Explorer not showing changes unless I hit F5 (refresh).

Scenario:

I have a page with a link that opens a modal window (where I do my editing). This works fine. I can make my changes and click my 'OK' button, which closes my modal window. The calling page does not show the changes unless I hit F5. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

Using Chrome and Fiddler, I can see that a GET is called right after my PUT (clicking the 'OK' button). In Internet Explorer, I don't see the GET after the PUT.

[This is using Internet Explorer 11]

Comment: Do you have any JS errors in IE? If you have a JS error only happening in IE sometime around when the modal closes, this could halt execution and prevent your GET request from being executed.

Comment: I have no JS errors. I do have 1 warning though.

I also noticed that if I have the Internet Explorer developer tools open it works fine.

Comment: Make sure that you are not in compatibility mode. When I've seen this happen before (having dev tools opens solves the problem), it is usually because you have compatibility mode enabled by default (which is causing a JS error). When you open dev tools, compatibility mode could be getting turned off, which causes the error to no longer occur.

Comment: Well...my app appears to work fine once it has been built and deployed. If I run 'ember server' on my local box, Internet Explorer still doesn't show the update until the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem in my Ember application, and as far as I can tell, it is a bug in Ember Data.  What version of Ember Data are you using, and are you still encountering the problem? We are using 1.0.0-beta.15 and investigating whether upgrading would fix the issue.

Possible work-arounds include detecting if the browser is IE and, if so, clearing the cache or forcing a refresh of the page.  I have yet to find any shims for this particular problem, but will update my answer when/if we come up with something that reliably works.

Comment: We had a bunch 'console.log' lines in our code. Once they were removed it worked fine.